# GCP Bucket name not visible/not available in metrics Explorer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a bucket which I created using Terraform. I have regular uploads on this bucket and everything is working fine. Now, I want to monitor the object count on this bucket, when I go to monitoring and select GCS Bucket and bucket name filter, it doesnt show this bucket. All other buckets are visible. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use `gsutil ls -lR gs://$BUCKETNAME` to list the objects manually.As per [doc](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-storage), The Object Count metric on Cloud Monitoring is sampled once per day; as such, there is typically a delay between the time the objects were uploaded, and when the data is reported on Cloud Monitoring. Have you checked the metric explorer after 1 day of bucket creation??

Comment: Is my answer helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [monitoring documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/metrics_gcp#gcp-storage) at storage/object_count section it is mentioned that `Total number of objects per bucket, grouped by storage class. This value is measured once per day, and the value is repeated at each sampling interval throughout the day.`  There is typically a delay between the time the objects were uploaded, and when the data is reported on Cloud Monitoring. Hence we need to check after 1 day when the first object was uploaded to the bucket. Manually we can list the objects by using command

```
gsutil ls -lR gs://$BUCKETNAME
```

Comment: Thanks i forgot to update the question, it was available directly in the console after 1 day